# Draw() in complexheatmap changes the order of row annotations

Tags: r, heatmap, complexheatmap

I am trying to add row annotations to my heatmap using complex heatmap.

```
s=Heatmap(total_df,
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
        column_split = factor(col_split$chr,levels = orderss),
        column_order = row.names(col_split),
        show_column_names = FALSE,
        )
```

and my annotation heatmap is

```
anno=Heatmap(order_df[,'type'],name='type' ,
        
        width = unit(1, "cm"),col=colors)
```

If i draw my annotation heatmap, it returns correct order

[image]

but when i try to combine it with primary heatmap using draw(), it changes the entire order.

```
draw(s+anno)
```

[image]

It would be great if anybody has an idea what is causing this. Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: That `Heatmap()` function is from what package?

Comment: @rmagn0 from complexheatmap (https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/index.html)

Comment: Sorry, I have never used that package. But I guess the order of the rows  between the two heatmaps have to match. So my guess is that the second heatmap (`anno`) is reordered to match the first (`s`). I will also guess there might be an option to draw the two heatmaps following the row order of the last and not the first.

Comment: @rmagn0 thank you ver much :) The order of them actually match, i ordered the annotation heatmap rows based on the main heatmap, when i combine, the order automatically changes for some reason.